# Exception calling "ImportBacPac" with "2" argument(s): "Could not import package"

Tags: azure, export, azure-sql-database

We are taking backup of a azure database (.bacpac file) from one server and restoring it to another server using powershell script and it worked well in sql server 2012. recently we run the same powershell script in sql server 2014 and we are facing the following exception while restoring the bacpac to the sql database

Exception calling "ImportBacPac" with "2" argument(s): "Could not import package."

and we are getting the exception

$Package =  [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.BacPackage]::Load($OutputFile)

$Services.ImportBacpac($Package, $DestinationDatabaseName)
Please help me to resolve the issue...

Thanks,

Prakash.